# Can someone help me debug this program

Tags: c++

Here is my code thus far, I think its doing its job right and i believe the problem is with my arrays.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const char FileName[] = "text.txt";

int main()
{
    string line;
    ifstream inMyStream(FileName);
    int c;
    int upperCaseCount[26] = { 0 };
    int lowerCaseCount[26] = { 0 };
    char oneLetter;

    if (inMyStream.is_open())
        {
            while (getline(inMyStream, line))
            {
                c += line.length();
            }

            for (unsigned n = 0; n < line.length(); ++n)
            {
                oneLetter = char(line[n]);
                if (oneLetter >= 'A' && oneLetter <= 'Z') 
                {
                    upperCaseCount[int(oneLetter) - 'A']++;
                }
                else if (oneLetter >= 'a' && oneLetter <= 'z')
                {
                    lowerCaseCount[int(oneLetter) - 'a']++;
                }
            }
        }
        inMyStream.close();

        cout << "Uppercase Characters: " << upperCaseCount << endl;
        cout << "Lowercase Characters: " << lowerCaseCount <<endl;
        cout << "Digits: " << c << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output I'm getting--->

> C:\Users\House\Desktop\Lab11>test
>
> Uppercase Characters: 0x28fcf4
>
> Lowercase Characters: 0x28fd5c
>
> Digits: 1959532772
>
> C:\Users\House\Desktop\Lab11>

Comment: There are a lot of things syntactically correct but unlikely what you desire, including uninitialized integers and printing out the address of arrays...

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: What unspecified values do you think should be generated?  I wonder what is the value of c immediately after the declaration of oneLetter?  Additionally, what did you expect cout to do with the address of an array of int?

Comment: _'Can someone help me debug this program'_ In general SO is intended the other way round: **You debug your program first**, and report any particular behaviors you don't understand, or that can't be explained by the c++ reference documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Working example for counting upperCases lowerCases and numbers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const char FileName[] = "text.txt";

int main()
{
    string line;
    ifstream inMyStream(FileName);
    int c=0;//counts digits
    int upperCount=0;//counts uppercases
    int lowerCount=0;//counts lowercases
    char oneLetter;

    if (inMyStream.is_open())
        {
            while (getline(inMyStream, line))
            {

                for (unsigned n = 0; n < line.length(); ++n)
                {
                    oneLetter = line[n];
                    if (oneLetter >= 'A' && oneLetter <= 'Z') 
                    {
                        upperCount++;
                    }
                    else if (oneLetter >= 'a' && oneLetter <= 'z')
                    {
                        lowerCount++;
                    }
                    else if (oneLetter >= '0' && oneLetter <= '9'){
                        c++;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        inMyStream.close();

        cout << "Uppercase Characters: " << upperCount << endl;
        cout << "Lowercase Characters: " << lowerCount <<endl;
        cout << "Digits: " << c << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

hope it helped ;)

Comment: so basically get rid of the array?

Comment: @Baalzamon Yeah, array is not necessary at all in this case, but just 3 variables that are 0 at the beginning and increment them.

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues (there is another big one that I left for you to debug).

You need to *initialize* the variable `c` to some useful starting value (perhaps 0).

You need to *iterate over your arrays* to print their contents. The odd looking outputs you currently get are addresses, not the array contents.

Comment: Okay i set int c = 0, but i think ive got a logical problem with my upper and lower case arrays, they are supposed to store the number of times each letter is a upper or lower case, but i dont need that output i just need the total number of each, should i just make a new variable and set it equal to those arrays then display that variable?

Comment: @Baalzamon: If you don't need to count each individual upper-case letter it seems you could just increment a single counter when you see _any_ upper-case letter.